# Mimic Bootstrap grid column properties via flexbox

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I have 6 logos of varying widths that I want to display in a responsive banner like so:

- 1 row of 6 on large screens
- 2 rows of 3 on medium screens
- 3 rows of 2 on small screens

This behavior is easy to accomplish in bootstrap by assigning the following class on each logo element: `col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4`

However, I'd like to use flexbox to enforce consistent spacing between each logo:

```
// html
<div class="logo-container">
  <img class="logo"/>
  <img class="logo"/>
  <img class="logo"/>
  <img class="logo"/>
  <img class="logo"/>
  <img class="logo"/>
</div>

// css
.logo-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

This works beautifully but only in the desktop view. Once I start shrinking the screen, `flex-wrap` kicks in to ensure the logos stay within the container, but the rows don't end up with equal numbers of logos in each row.

Instead of 2 rows of 3 logos, I end up with 1 row of 5 logos + 1 row of 1 logo, or 1 row of 4 logos + 1 row of 2 logos.

Comment: Simply copy bootstraps media queries and reset the flex-basis to a proper percent ... or use bootstrap 4, which is based on Flexbox

Comment: I agree with @LGSon - just use bootstrap 4. Using media queries, are you looking for something like this? https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/Xabaax you could also add `.col-` classes and use that instead of `.logo` in the media queries

Comment: @MichaelCoker Combing `calc` with `flex` shorthand for `flex-basis` won't work in IE. Use longhand `flex-basis`

Comment: Thanks @LGSon! I'll use your first suggestion... our app is pretty big so upgrading to bootstrap 4 might be a heavier task than expected. Unless BS4 is backwards compatible

Comment: @LGSon thanks! reference to the bug on mdn https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex#Browser_compatibility and updated the pen.

Comment: @robinnnnn You can check here when it comes to backward compatibility and migration: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/